# I am getting error in my model code in play 1.2.4

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

The table is not creating in my database.All the code that i had      written is correct but I can't find the error

```
21:21:56,433 ERROR ~ Unsuccessful: create table Student (id bigint not null auto_increment, Branch varchar(255), Div varchar(255), Mobile varchar(255), Name varchar(255), NumBacklogs integer not null, aggr double precision not null, email varchar(255), skID_SkID integer, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
    21:21:56,433 ERROR ~ You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Div varchar(255), Mobile varchar(255), Name varchar(255), NumBacklogs integer no' at line 1
    21:21:56,743 ERROR ~ Unsuccessful: alter table Student add index FKF3371A1B229B2525 (skID_SkID), add constraint FKF3371A1B229B2525 foreign key (skID_SkID) references Skills (SkID)
    21:21:56,743 ERROR ~ Table 'placement2.student' doesn't exist
```

Model class

```
    package models;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    import play.data.validation.Required;

    import play.db.jpa.Model;


    @Entity
    public class Student extends Model{


        @Required
        public String Name;

        @Required
        public  String Branch;

        @Required
        public String Div;

        @Required
        public  String email;

        @Required
        public String Mobile;

        @Required
        public double aggr;

        @Required
        public int NumBacklogs;

        @ManyToOne
        @Required
        public Skills skID;



        public Student(String Name, String Branch, String Div, String email,                                     `           String Mobile,double aggr, int NumBacklogs,Skills skID){`
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Branch = Branch;
            this.Div = Div;
            this.email = email;
            this.Mobile = Mobile;
            this.aggr = aggr;
            this.NumBacklogs = NumBacklogs;
            this.skID = skID;


        }

    }
```

Why the table student is not created in my database although I had written the above code?

Answer (score 0):

[`Div`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is a mysql reserve word

You can do

```
@Required 
@Column(name="`div`")        //adding backticks
public String Div;
```

or

change the name of variable